# NotificationChannel not found in Unity when API is lower that 26

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm using an android library in my unity project that does some stuff with notification.

There's a block of code in the library that imports `android.app.NotificationChannel`. It would be like:

`library.setNotificationListener(...)`

and it would be referenced to a java file which is importing notification channel.

If I run my app **on Android 8.0 or higher, it works**, but if I test it on a lower API like 25, it says:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.NotificationChannel
          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.NotificationChannel
          at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source)
          at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke(Native Method)
          at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a(Unknown Source)
          at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**The library works fine on a lower 26 android in a native app**

**Why this class is found in API 26 and not found in lower ones?**
*The code handles the API version and no android 8.0 specific API will be invoked when lower than 26. It's just import of one.*

Should I add some configuration for these kinda situations in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** (2021, 03)

I managed to solve this issue by moving the `android.app.NotificationChannel` usage out of the file I was working with on Unity side. In other words:

1. When working with native (Java) `ClassA` in Unity side using `AndroidJavaObject`, it should not directly import `android.app.NotificationChannel` (Generally APIs that are not available in a lower versions)
2. Move the import into another class and make a bridge from `ClassA` to `ClassB` to get the needed functionality

---

The problem can happen on two cases:

1. `CompileSDKVersion`

   if the compile sdk is lower than 26, this class will not be in the class path and therefore you might end up getting this error...
2. **MultiDex**
   If the class is needed before MultiDex init, like in coroutines, you will need to exclude it using `multidex-config` file to exclude this and keep this class in the mainDex.

   For more information checkout the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#multidexkeepfile-property).

Answer (score 0):

NotificationChannel(s) were [introduced in Android O](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) (API 26).

I do not know much about Unity but in a native Android app, we do the following to set up the channels.

```
private fun setupChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = createNotificationChannel()
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createNotificationChannel() = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).apply {
    description = channelDescription
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's exactly how the code is handled. The problem is that the `android.app.NotificationChannel` is not found. The SDK works fine on a native app.

Comment: what is your target and compile sdk versions?

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to call NotificationChannel class when running on lower api?

Comment: Target is the highest as Unity engine sets it. But I have no idea if it's possible to set compile sdk version in Unity.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/111
It may just be that your compileSdkVersion is less than API 26. If you can figure that out, it may be helpful.

Comment: I'll check out the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android 7.1.1 (which is API 25) and below, don’t have (and need) the NotificationChannel. It means that if you created a notification in app which was developed in lower api then 25, this notification won’t show up if you’ll install this app on api 26 (android 8.0) and above - simply because they do need it.